# JQM: Dynamic nested collapsibles - $(collapsible).collapsible() & $(collapsible).trigger('create')

Tags: jquery-mobile, dom

I am new with JQM, but I have read quite a few blogs and documentation but this knowledge is not helping me here. I have read about [page create vs refresh events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html). With the examples I have seen on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nVgLM/1/) the create event works fine. But when I tried to code, it doesn't seem to work.

I am dynamically injecting collapsibes into the DOM on expand. Somebody please point out of what I'm doing wrong. For me $(collapsible).collapsible() & $(collapsible).trigger('create') do not work when done on button click. The div gets added to the markup but doesn't get the style of a collapsible.

The same functions work well when invoked on $(document).ready function. But I have a lot of data and simply can't bring in everything on that event.

snippet of code tried on document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Delete the existing content, if any
    $('#tdDynamic').empty();

    // Append a new collapsible and store it into a JQuery object
    $('#tdDynamic').html('<div id="collapsible" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c"></div>');

    // Append the list header and store it into a JQuery object
    $('#collapsible').html('<h3>NAME of a person</h3>');

    $('#collapsible').append('<div id="collapse1"  data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="c" data-collapsed="false">'
                            + '<h3>Im a nested collapsible with a child collapsible</h3>'
                            + '<p>Im a child collapsible.</p>'
                        + '</div>');

    $('#collapse1').append('<div id="collapse2" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d" data-collapsed="false">'
                             + '<h3>Nested inside again.</h3>'
                              + '<p>Three levels deep now.</p>'
                            + '</div>');

    $('#collapse1').collapsible();
    $('#collapse2').collapsible();
    $('#collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

Here is a snippet:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSort', function () {
$('#tdDynamic').empty();
var pg = $('#ddlPG option:selected').text();
var ch = $('#ddlCH option:selected').text();
var so = $('#ddlSO option:selected').text();
var ae = $('#ddlAE option:selected').text();
var dt = $('#txtSDate').val();
var format = "";
if ($('#radio-choice-0a').is(':checked')) format = "M";
else format = "D";

var data = ExecuteSynchronously('../WebService.asmx'
, 'Get_SalesReport_Apk', { userCode: 1, level: '', channel: ch
, programme: pg, salesoffice: so, accexec: ae, dateFormat: format, date: dt });
//window.ChDataLoader.getSalesSeaarch_WBS('', ch, pg, so, ae, format, dt);
//$('#tdDynamic').append(data);
if (data.d != "" && data.d != null) {
    var arrList = data.d.split('^');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrList.length; i++) {
        var arr = arrList[i].split('#');
        var Programme = arr[0];

        var arr2 = arr[1].split('><');
        var revenue = arr2[0];
        var time = arr2[1];

        // Append a new collapsible and store it into a JQuery object                   
        $('#tdDynamic').append('<div id="collapsible_PG' 
        + i + '" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"'
        +' data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c"'
                              + ' ></div>');

        // Append the list header and store it into a JQuery object
        var collapsible = $('#collapsible_PG' + i);

        collapsible.append('<h3 id="h3Text_PG'
        + i + '">' + Programme + '~&nbsp;' 
        + time + '&nbsp;~&nbsp;' + revenue + '</h3>');
        //var h3Text = $('#h3Text' + i);

        var h3Text_PG = $('#h3Text_PG' + i);
        h3Text_PG.bind('expand', onexpand);
        h3Text_PG.bind('collapse', oncollapse);
        collapsible.collapsible();
    }
}

});

function oncollapse(event) {
//alert(event.target.id);
}

function onexpand(event) {                    
//alert(event.target.id);
//$('#'+event.target.id).empty();
var arrPGName = $(event.target).text().split('~');
var pg = arrPGName[0];
var ch = $('#ddlCH option:selected').text();
var so = $('#ddlSO option:selected').text();
var ae = $('#ddlAE option:selected').text();
var dt = $('#txtSDate').val();
var format = "";
if ($('#radio-choice-0a').is(':checked')) format = "M";
else format = "D";

var dataso = ExecuteSynchronously('../WebService.asmx'
, 'Get_SalesReport_Apk'
, { userCode: 1, level: 'SO', channel: ch, programme: pg
, salesoffice: so, accexec: ae, dateFormat: format, date: dt });
//window.ChDataLoader.getSalesSeaarch_WBS('', ch, pg, so, ae, format, dt);
//$('#tdDynamic').append(data);

if (dataso.d != "" && dataso.d != null) {
    //$('#' + event.target.id).remove();
    var arrList = dataso.d.split('^');
    //alert(arrList.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrList.length; i++) {
        var arr = arrList[i].split('#');
        var SO = arr[0];

        var arr2 = arr[1].split('><');
        var revenue = arr2[0];
        var time = arr2[1];
        //alert(event.target.id);
        // Append a new collapsible and store it into a JQuery object                   
        $('<div id="collapsible_SO' + i 
        + '" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"'
        +' data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c"'
        + ' ></div>').appendTo('#' +event.target.id);

        // Append the list header and store it into a JQuery object
        var collapsible = $('#collapsible_SO' + i);

        $('<h3 id="h3Text_SO' + i + '">' + SO 
        + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + time + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' 
        + revenue + '</h3>').appendTo('#collapsible_SO' + i);
        //var h3Text = $('#h3Text' + i);

        var h3Text_SO = $('#h3Text_SO' + i);
        h3Text_SO.bind('expand', onexpand_SO);                            
    }
    $('#'+event.target.id).trigger('create');
    //$('#page1').trigger('create');
}

}

function onexpand_SO(event) {
$('#'+ event.target.id).collapsible();
//alert($(event.target).text());
}
```

When I did an inspect element, I found that the collapsibles do not get injected within
`<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-c" aria-hidden="false"></div>` tag. Instead they get appended after it.

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-c" aria-hidden="false">
</div>
<div id="collapsible_SO0" data-role="collapsible" 
data-collapsed="false" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c">
<h3 id="h3Text_SO0">Bengaluru</h3></div>
<div id="collapsible_SO1" data-role="collapsible"
data-collapsed="false" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c">
<h3 id="h3Text_SO1">Delhi</h3></div>
<div id="collapsible_SO2" data-role="collapsible"
data-collapsed="false" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c">
<h3 id="h3Text_SO2">Kolkata</h3></div>
<div id="collapsible_SO3" data-role="collapsible"
data-collapsed="false" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="c">
<h3 id="h3Text_SO3">Mumbai</h3></div>
```

Page looks like the following:
[image: I want the collapsibles to be added inside the first collapsible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a soultion to this by appending to `.appendTo('#' +event.target.id + ' ui-collapsible-content');`.

Comment: I found this after alot of research over the internet. I am a noob with jquery mobile.